# Asp.net EF how to create 1 to many table relation

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a class in my model with authorized users list:

```
public class Album
    {
        public virtual List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public List<User> AuthorizedUsers { get; set; }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
        public User Creator { get; set; }
        public string CreatorId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long CoverPhotoId { get; set; }

    }
```

Now I would like EF to create a table such:
AlbumAuthorized where at each album Id many users Id will correspond.

So that when I pick an album I will know which users are authorized to see it, by loading the list of authorized users (using the mentioned table). Ho do I tell EF that?
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: @Isma thanks I can do that manually, but I hoped entity framework has some way to build the data model itself

Comment: I have added the table manually, as I could not find a way to make ef understand what I was trying to do. I ask many questions true and I usually take time to comment on the answers given. But in this case I add not much time on hand to explain myself on the answer given.